# Getting Illegal characters in path exception after enabling HttpUnhandledException

Tags: asp.net, .net, path, character

I added to my .net app in the `Global.asax.cs` file error trapping like so

```
 void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpUnhandledException httpUnhandledException = new 
        HttpUnhandledException(Server.GetLastError().Message, Server.GetLastError());

  SystemFunctions.SendEmailWithErrors(httpUnhandledException.GetHtmlErrorMessage());
    }
```

When I run my app I get an Illegal Characters in Path exception in the Designer.Cs funciton below..

```
public OptionsEntities() : base("name=OptionsEntities", "OptionsEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

If I just continue on the app keeps going. If I remove the code block from the Global.asax.cs, the error goes away. Any ideas on where this may be coming from??

Comment: Can you test with removing each specific line in the Application_Error code block to see what it is, or is it the fact that Application_Error exists at all that causes the error?

Comment: the error crops up only when the Application_Error function is there. Like I said, if I remove that, there are no problems...

Comment: But does an empty Application_Error code block cause the error or just when you have the code inside it?

Answer (score 0):

try to relpace "name=OptionsEntities",with "OptionsEntities" may be it help you